# Inserting XAML elements through C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm just starting with Universal Windows Platform and actually C# as well (I've got a C background) and just trying to get my feet wet with a basic accounting app meant to keep track of a checkbook. The way it works is simple, the user either presses + or - buttons and specifies the name of the transaction and the amount either credited or debited, hits ok and that transaction is inserted as a row.

So it would look something like this

```
Gas       ($20)  1/5/17   _delete_button_
Paycheck   $2400 1/3/17   _delete_button_

Total      $2380
```

....

So each row has 2 editable text boxes (name and amount), one textfield for date, and one button to delete that row.

Now my first instinct as a C programmer is just to create a struct with those variables and every time user inserts a row just populate the struct and push it on a stack. However I just want to make sure that this is the best way to do this and I'm not missing some feature of XAML that would let me do this.

Comment: What kind of UI element is housing all of the rows

Comment: XAML is the language that usually defines the view, although the syntax can be used to bind to objects in your model (ie C# or F# or whatever). So, there is not really a "feature" of XAML that allows you to create and manipulate collections... other than tying into the struct or whatever model you are using.

Comment: @Aaron Thomas I came across something like ResourceDictionary but I think it's used for brushes and such but maybe I thought I can do something like define a template for a row in XAML and then just insert that template. Because right now I'm just basically circumventing XAML and just progamming all the rows in C#

Comment: @TimAkgayev are you having the user add the new data through a popup form or just using the blank row at the bottom? if you are not using the blank row, a feature you could think about using is what AaronThomas mentioned which is with binding. Are you maintaining you objects in some sort of collection?

Comment: @TimAkgayev just saw your new comment. i personally would have a class that describes each line item and have that stored in some sort of collection that is bound to the UI element. It really depends on how complex of an accounting app you are trying to make.

For example, lets say you want to have your app provide a search feature by expense type. If you are storing your data in the grid only, it will become very messy whereas if your objects are stored in a collection you can just display only certain elements and still have all your objects stored and can be rolled back

Comment: I thought of just inserting a row straight away if a user pressed on an empty spot in a grid, and then just having the two boxes for name and amount editable. So I should just have a class with those items and then bind them to an insert button? I'm going to look into c# collections as I'm kind of learning it as I go along with this project. But in general I would definitely want to make the app as robust as possible touching on many features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Now my first instinct as a C programmer is just to create a struct
>   with those variables and every time user inserts a row just populate
>   the struct and push it on a stack. However I just want to make sure
>   that this is the best way to do this and I'm not missing some feature
>   of XAML that would let me do this."

This question is dangerously close to not meeting the requirements for a good question because it is too broad, but I will answer anyway due to remembering the pain I went through with XAML when new. Whether new or experienced (and I am at most in the "intermediate" category), it seems XAML has its bits that will always send you looking for help. But I digress.

The standard is to create your model, then somehow connect (or "bind") the appropriate parts of the model to your view.

You would use **C#** (actually can use VB or F# or others also) for your model. This is where you would create your "struct" you are referring to. This would define your individual transaction. Then, create a collection of these transactions, again in your model.

In **XAML**, you *bind* to this collection. You have a control (a visual element in your view) that displays all transactions. You have a control for specifying the name of a specific transaction, for selecting a transaction, for inserting, for deleting, etc. All of these controls interact with the model through the bindings.

So, to answer your question, **yes you are missing a feature of XAML. It is called binding.** Not to be sarcastic but unfortunately, binding is a technology worthy of months of study. Sorry, but you will want to go back to C with no UI at first. Keep at it! If you want to do the universal app thing, it is worth it. You may even find yourself liking (parts of) it.

Link to get thou started:

[WPF and other XAML-related](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Note that Aaron's link is for WPF not for UWP. For UWP data binding start at https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/data-binding/index

Comment: that is an excellent link, thanks. The first one had me scratching my head if wpf and uwp are similar.

Comment: @TimAkgayev: WPF and UWP have nothing in common, other than both choosing XAML as their object instantiation markup language. Particularly with respect to data binding, there are significant differences with the new `{x:Bind}` syntax introduced in Windows 10.

Comment: Is there a single document that explains all these techs and appropriate uses of them, another thread I read said they're both similar except WPF is less restricted since it's not sandboxed.